# Visual Studio 2019 horizontal scrollbar on diferences

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

When I try to check changes using team explorer on visual studio 2019, if I open any file to check differences I cannot see horizontal scrollbar.

[image: Visual Studio differences cheker]

Is there any config I have to modify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer myself:
The scrollbar is there, but it's only visible when the width is large enough. The tick and the "No problems found" message let too litle space for the scrollbar.

BTW, at first glance I feel like this version GUI of VS is worse than previous version. Just an opinion.